# Using jasmine to compare arrays fails in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, unit-testing, jasmine

Apparently ie8 has three properties that get appended to the resulting array from a call to `String.prototype.match()`:

`input`, `index` and `lastIndex`

([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7df7sf4x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx))

The result is that array comparison fails when using Jasmine's `.toEqual()` matcher.

I'm still working my way up the learning curve on unit testing, so I'm just curious of what the right way is to do deal with this failure.

The following works but seems a bit lame:

```
 numArray = str.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
 if (numArray && numArray.input) {
      delete numArray.index;
      delete numArray.input;
      delete numArray.lastIndex;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Underscore's 'difference' method can help -

```
expect(_.difference(['item1', 'item2'], ['item1', 'item2'])).toEqual([]);
```

http://underscorejs.org/#difference

Answer (score 1):

I think @monkeyboy's answer is not correct.

Since `underscore.difference()` returns the elements of the first array that are not present in the second array: `_.difference([1],[1,2]);` is also `[]` so the test will pass when it shouldn't. I couldn't find a way to solve this using underscore.

So i'm using:

`expect(JSON.stringify(result)).toBe(JSON.stringify(expected));`

which works as expected.

Anyway, i'd like to know how others are doing this.